# I18n stopped working

Tags: django, django-i18n

I always use this script to compile django.po and it was always working:

```
#!/bin/sh
django-admin.py makemessages -a
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

Suddenly it stopped working, with this error:

```
$ i18n.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Python34/Scripts/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 533,
 in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessag
es.py", line 283, in handle_noargs
    potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessag
es.py", line 299, in build_potfiles
    file_list = self.find_files(".")
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessag
es.py", line 358, in find_files
    ignored_roots = [os.path.normpath(p) for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings
.STATIC_ROOT)]
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessag
es.py", line 358, in <listcomp>
    ignored_roots = [os.path.normpath(p) for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings
.STATIC_ROOT)]
  File "c:\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 491, in normpath
    if path.startswith(special_prefixes):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
processing file django.po in c:\Users\Debora\workspace\opti\opti2.0\project\loca
le\pt_BR\LC_MESSAGES
```

Anyone has got any ideas?

I don't know what caused this. recently I updated django 1.7 to 1.7.1, installed some packages unrelated, that's what I remember doing that could have affected.

Comment: I had the same issue afer upgrading to Django 1.7, and solved it running those commands using `manage.py`

Comment: didn't work for me, same problem.

Comment: cor's comment should be the answer... Using manage.py is way more simple since Django 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings.py file.

This is a [bug in Django 1.7.1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23717) and should be removed in Django 1.7.2

(Since [Django 1.6.2 `STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#static-root) defaults to `None`, before `''`.)

Comment: It seemed to be a bug. Now it is working again, I didn't change anything. Thanks yofee.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue after upgrading to Django 1.7

I fixed it by specifying the settings module each time I run `django-admin.py`:

```
cd ~/myproject/myproject # where the ``locale`` folder exists
PYTHONPATH=~/myproject django-admin.py makemessages --settings=myproject.settings -l <language>
```

Update: It is a bug fixed in Django 1.7.2 see: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7.2/
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23717

Answer (score 2):

Problem is when You didn't setup your `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings value.
After setting this like:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I'm using `make_messages.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for dir in `find -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -iname ".*"`; do
    echo $dir
    tmp=$(basename $dir)
    dir="$tmp"
    skip_this=0
    for tmp in static media; do
        if [ "$dir" = "$tmp" ]; then
            skip_this=1
            break
        fi
    done

    if [ "$skip_this" = "1" ]; then
        echo Skipping $dir
        continue
    fi

    cd `dirname $0`/$dir
    if [ ! -d locale ] ; then
        echo Creating 'locale' directory
        mkdir locale
    fi
    ../manage.py makemessages -l pl -l en -l de
        cd ..
done
```

and after executing `make_messages.sh`:

```
./static_page
processing locale pl
processing locale en
processing locale de
./common
Creating locale directory
processing locale pl
processing locale en
processing locale de
```

And this is my `compile_messages.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for dir in `find -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -iname ".*"`; do
        echo $dir
        tmp=$(basename $dir)
        dir="$tmp"
        skip_this=0
        for tmp in static static_custom media; do
                if [ "$dir" = "$tmp" ]; then
                        skip_this=1
                        break
                fi
        done

        if [ "$skip_this" = "1" ]; then
                echo Skipping $dir
                continue
        fi

        cd `dirname $0`/$dir
        ../manage.py compilemessages -l pl -l en -l de
        cd ..
done
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me. But wondering why this issue occurred with 1.7.1 but not with 1.7

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems using Django 1.7.1.

I fixed it by changing the command: `django-admin.py` to `python manage.py`.

So my entire command goes like this:

`python manage.py makemessages --locale=en --ignore=templates/admin --ignore=project/settings.py`

Comment: I've been stuckon this too, an your solution works for me, but only when I use `sudo`. Then I have to change the permissions. Which is really weird, but you helped me find some way to do it, so thanks.

Comment: Great to hear it. I never had to use sudo to run a python command but maybe you had created your project or your env with sudo, but I really don't know why. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## first Define your local path for makemessages

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)
```

In terminal

$python manage.py makemessages -l pl

go the folder and open the file edit the .po file

Then in terminal

$python manage.py compilemessages

it works fine in Django 1.7 and upgraded too.

i think it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same ussue. I tried to run with django-admin, and got this issue.

When I run it with manage.py, it runs ok.

```
python manage_local.py makemessages -l cs --settings=gprojects.settings_local
```

Use manage.py, manage_local.py is my alternated version.

Comment: Didn't work for me yet, same problem. :( i'll continue trying.