# django-admin.py makemessages fails

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I had created language-files with `django-admin.py makemessages -a`

A little bit development later all attempts to create *.po files are failing with:

```
django-admin.py makemessages  -v 3 -a
examining files with the extensions: .html and .txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",         line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line     377, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line    288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 283, in handle_noargs
potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 299, in build_potfiles
file_list = self.find_files(".")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 358, in find_files
ignored_roots = [os.path.normpath(p) for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.STATIC_ROOT)]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 358, in <listcomp>
ignored_roots = [os.path.normpath(p) for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.STATIC_ROOT)]
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/posixpath.py", line 335, in normpath
initial_slashes = path.startswith(sep)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I tried it with several file extensions and -ignore patterns.
Do you have any hints?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure ```settings.MEDIA_ROOT``` and ```settings.STATIC_ROOT``` exist and are valid?

Comment: I have triied to set them like this:
`STATIC_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)`

or with '/var/www/projectroot/static'

Comment: Okay that is strange: I use vagrant for development and the described  error happens there, whereas every other command do not produce a failure. I' ve tried it on the host machine and everything works as it should.

Comment: Thats not a duplicate it is the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23717) introduced in Django 1.7.1. You can fix this by updating your Django to the latest version using:

```
  pip install -U django
```

P.S. Related StackOverflow questions and answers on this matter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675881/i18n-stopped-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222384/django-18n-makemessages-does-not-create-po-files).

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem since django 1.7. I use manage.py to make messages instead of django-admin.py excluding the environment folder:

```
python manage.py makemessages --locale=en --ignore=venv/*
```

Answer (score 1):

This does work with me:

python manage.py makemessages --locale=en --ignore=venv/*