# django 18n : makemessages does not create .po files

Tags: python, django

I have a django project .
In this project,there is an app called `core`

I `cd core` and try  `python ../manage.py makemessages -l tw`

But it didn't create the `django.po` file,
I also try `django-admin.py makemessages -l tw` , but there is error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/winsome/env/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
management.execute_from_command_line()
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 283, in handle_noargs
potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 299, in build_potfiles
file_list = self.find_files(".")
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 358, in find_files
ignored_roots = [os.path.normpath(p) for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.STATIC_ROOT)]
File "/Users/winsome/env/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 327, in normpath
initial_slashes = path.startswith('/')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Please help me , Thank you

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',  )

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), )
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('tw', ugettext('Chinese')), )

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.core.context_processors.i18n",)
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ("js", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'js')),
    ("css", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'css')),
    ("img", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'img')),
    ("video", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'video')),
    ("file", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'file')),
    # ("fonts", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'fonts')),
)
```

templates/english/index.html

```
{% extends 'global/base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

<ul id="header">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="{% url 'core:maininfo' %}#firstPage">{% trans "About" %}</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="{% url 'core:maininfo' %}#secondPage">{% trans "Features" %}</a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="{% url 'core:maininfo' %}#3rdPage">{% trans "Press" %}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace please?

Comment: Post your `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` as well.

Comment: OK I don't have ````MEDIA_ROOT```` in settings.py

Comment: So there's your problem.

Comment: but I didn't use it. what should I set?

Comment: Are you using Django 1.7?

Comment: Yes. I use django 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to [a bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23717) in Django 1.7 that has already been fixed. If you downloaded Django using git, you can do a `git pull`. If not re-install Django by cloning the development version or use an older stable Django version.

Comment: I use pip and my version is 1.7.1. Finally I use old version and solve the problem. Thanks!